# Installing printer Epson SX235W in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I am fairly new to installing/fixing things on Ubuntu if this does not involve the graphical interface of Software Centre.

I want to get my Epson Stylus SX235W working, but unable to do it so far.

Perhaps someone can suggest something. So far, I have tried to find a network printer by earlier pressing Wifi on rooter and printer, but no connection has been established.

When trying to find a driver through ipp14, cups it asks about printer's make and model, but this model does not show up.

In terminal I also haven't gone far, as managed to install 'lsb' package only (command: sudo apt-get install lsb). Installing 'rpm' file downloaded earlier was unsuccessful as the command was not recognised on terminal. Well, terminal is not yet my strong side...

How to install the printer in Ubuntu 14.04?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the driver from [Epson Drivers Site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX).

Search there for your printer (enter "SX235"), download deb files according to your architecture (amd64 or i386).

I recommend first choice "full feature" driver.

Copy them to "Epson" folder in your home folder and run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Epson/*.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

But before Ubuntu could download Epson drivers automatically, when you add an Epson printer in System Settings. Did you try that?

Same way you can install scanner driver. Download `iscan` and `iscan-data` packages and install them same way. For current Ubuntu releases you need to download packages with `ltdl7` in name.

Also `iscan-network` can be installed for scanning over the net.

To setup network plugin you need to add line `net <your_printer_ip>` to file `/etc/epkowa.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

I think lsb should be there already.
I managed to get it work just installing drivers: (they gave couple errors though as I am running 16.04 and some newer softwares)

Go to the manufacturer site and download driver for Linux:

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Next I installed scanner program from Ubuntu´s Applications and last I edited following SANE file through terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/epson.conf
```

And I did add there my printers static ip settings (autodiscovery in case that you use DHCP on your router):

```
net 192.168.2.2 # (Check yours from the printer)
net autodiscovery
```

I had also epson2.conf file and you may want to edit that too if not working or just to be sure. Just add the same line(s).

"SANE (Scanner Access Now Easy) is the linux way of scanning. sane supports a great many scanners, and the community around SANE adds support for more scanners all the time. By and large, most supported scanners are plug and play simple (plug them in and your ready to scan). However, some scanners will require manual installation."